# Error creating mongock bean when deploying on docker

Tags: spring-boot, mongock

I am using Mongck to migrate data in my Spring Boot application. Spring Boot application runs perfectly locally. But when running on docker, the following error occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongockInitializingBeanRunner' defined in class path resource [vn/vnpt/icode/svc/config/config/MongockConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/MongoDatabaseFactory

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

see the full logs [here](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock/issues/308)

Here is the dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api'
    
    implementation 'com.github.cloudyrock.mongock:mongock-bom:4.3.7'
    implementation 'com.github.cloudyrock.mongock:mongodb-springdata-v3-driver:4.3.7'
    implementation 'com.github.cloudyrock.mongock:mongock-spring-v5:4.3.7'


    
    
    implementation 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-kubernetes:2.0'
    implementation 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka:3.0.1.RELEASE'
    
//    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20201115'
    
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

and the content of MongockConfig class:

```java
    @Bean
    public MongockSpring5.MongockInitializingBeanRunner mongockInitializingBeanRunner(ApplicationContext springContext, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        boolean migrationsEnabled = mongoEnabled;
        return MongockSpring5.builder()
                .setDriver(SpringDataMongoV3Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoTemplate))
                .addChangeLogsScanPackages(List.of(changeLogsScanPackage))
                .setSpringContext(springContext)
                .setEnabled(migrationsEnabled)
                .buildInitializingBeanRunner();
    }
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work when run on docker. Is my `mongockInitializingBeanRunner` method incorrect.

Someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in this [Github issue](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock/issues/308), the issue was resolved by upgrading to version 4.3.7.